# Input Field returns undefined but works after changing the value

Tags: javascript, undefined

When I first click on this function. It returns an undefined value. When I click on the function again, this code works fine in this form and every form after that.

alert(characters[x].ac+"/"+this.value+"/"+this.ac) returns undefined/undefined/0 initially.
It returns 26/undefined/0 when I click the function again and captures the value just the way I want. So it is basically saying that characters[x].ac is undefined when I initially click the bolded text to make the text field appear.

How do make the 'undefined' listing go away. It happens when I change the value of an array for the first time but works fine in the same array in every form after that.

```
function askAc(x) {
    if(this.ac!=0) {
        response=this.ac;
        characters[x].setAc(response);
        this.ac=0;
    } else {
        response="<input class=widgetstyle onClick=_setAc(this.value) size=2 type=text value="+characters[x].ac+">";
        characters[x].setAc(response);
    }
}
function _setAc(x) {
    this.ac=x;
    this.refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your input field have a value="" attribute or is it missing? a missing value attr may result in undefined (maybe just in some browsers).

It is not clear from your code which input field you are accessing.

Comment: menuContents+="<tr><td>ac:<b onClick=askAc("+this.index+")>"+this.ac+"</b>" there is no value att here. How can I assign one if the tag is a <b>?

Comment: I'm sure that you have the right answer. Now I just need to figure out how to assign a value to a tag that isn't an input tag. Any suggestions?

Comment: <b> has not value attribute. if you add .value to your <b> object then it is not an equivalent to value="" it's just an object variable. In your case you must make sure to initialize the .value manually before the first use.